# Google Play - How can internal tester view the production version?

Tags: android, google-play

We want to start using google play for testing (We used Firebase until now).

One of our tests is version upgrade (from the current production version on google play to the new production version which we want to publish to google play), but we can't figure out how to do this - in google play.

When internal tester opens the test link, he always see the internal version.

The test page at the bottom has the option to 'Install the public version on Google Play', however, clicking on that link, opens the internal version.

[image]

The way we deal with that right now is by having two google accounts on a device, and only one of them is for the internal tester.
In this way, the other account still sees the current production version.

Is there a way for internal tester to view the production version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two possible solutions:

1. The tester would have to leave the internal testing program by clicking the "Leave the Program" button above. They would then see the Production version
2. The other way would be to put the Production version in both your channels - Internal Testing and Production